# Upgrading Sonar to 4.0

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have upgraded the Sonarqube to 4.0. The code which uses this sonar is running on jdk1.7, but the machine where the sonar and bamboo are running have JAVA_HOME and PATH set to jdk1.6. So I have set two properties in wrapper.conf.

```
set.JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java
```

My tests are failing and giving some weird problems, here's some output:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Z cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Is there more output?  Maybe somewhere in the source we can see where an array of Booleans is being cast to String

Comment: Hi @demongolem <br> It's not allowing me to put the whole error stack. Saying it's too long